# liquibase always creates procedure in public schema in Postgres

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Postgres using liquibase and passing schemaName but it always creates the stored procedure under public schema.

My change set looks like

```
> <createProcedure relativeToChangelogFile="true"
>         dbms="postgresql"
>         path="storedProcedures/cirrus_UTC_Timestamp.sql"
>         schemaName="cirrusdb"
>         procedureName="cirrus_UTC_Timestamp">
>         </createProcedure>
```

Debug log from Liquibase command

```
C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml:
C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml::8.2.0.0-1::guptaa8:
Computed checksum for create Procedure:[
  dbms="postgresql"
  path="storedProcedures/cirrus_UTC_Timestamp.sql"
  procedureName="cirrus_UTC_Timestamp"
  relativeToChangelogFile="true"
  schemaName="cirrusdb" ] as 75cfb2062231cfb7a0813a82a4f62764 DEBUG 11/18/15 2:38 PM: liquibase: 
C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml:
 C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml::8.2.0.0-1::guptaa8:
Computed checksum for 7:75cf 
b2062231cfb7a0813a82a4f62764:7:0a8a327c03ced9a7b29acb65fee085b9 as 
0591c7cae23e75e7ea48680d9e7fb742 DEBUG 11/18/15 2:38 PM: liquibase: 
C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml:
C:/views/P4V/cirrus_dev/cirrus/main/build/package/src/main/resources/scripts/MasterDBChangeLogs.xml::8.2.0.0-1::guptaa8:
Computed checksum for 7:0591 c7cae23e75e7ea48680d9e7fb742: as 
ae8a55a46214d182fab4b59f8765b90d DEBUG 11/18/15 2:38 PM: liquibase: 
Release Database Lock DEBUG 11/18/15 2:38 PM: liquibase: Executing 
UPDATE database command: UPDATE cirrusdb.databasechangeloglock SET 
LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1 INFO 
11/18/15 2:38 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock 
Liquibase Update Successful
```

Liquibase Version: 3.4.1, Postgres version 9.3

Comment: What is the content of `cirrus_UTC_Timestamp.sql`?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cirrus_UTC_Timestamp() RETURNS timestamp without time zone AS $$

DECLARE utc_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;

BEGIN
 SELECT current_timestamp at time zone 'utc' into utc_timestamp;

RETURN utc_timestamp;

END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that liquibase (up to 3.4.2) does not support the schemaName on the createProcedure tag, its 'informational' only:

Source : https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2626

Ticket Description :

> Currently the createProcedure schemaName is not used, it is just for
>   informational purposes. Change createProcedure so if schemaName is
>   specified, it will use the SqlParser class to find the name of the
>   procedure in the body and either prepend the schema or replace the
>   existing schema with the given schemaName. Add a new
>   liquibase.useProcedureSchema=true|false flag which if false will not
>   do the parsing but instead add an ALTER SESSION USE DEFAULT SCHEMA...
>   statements before and after the create procedure SQL.